# A replacement for ImageMagick - Rmagick library?

Tags: ruby, rmagick

Is there any library that can replace [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)?

It´s over 2 yeas ago since the gem has been updated. The installation process is still a pain. It´s broken.

Example having followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows):

```
C:\Ruby192\bin>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-7 2012-04-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

It should be installed, right?

```
C:\Rails\myapp>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'RMagick'
LoadError: no such file to load -- RMagick
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Then when I am using the ruby console it gives a error. Have run `bundle install` and all kind of other solutions and followed several guides, installed and uninstalled a thousand times.

Therefore I am looking for a replacement for the RMagick library. Either a Javascript library/plugin or a ruby gem.

Comment: I think it´s case sensitive using Windows 7 64 bit and Ruby version 1.9.2p136. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407062/difference-between-require-rmagick-and-require-rmagick-mac-vs-debian

Comment: `It should be installed, right?` ImageMagick is installed, but I can't see, that rmagick is installed (step 4 in the description).

Comment: Followed this guide and it worked! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully used ["mini_magick"](http://rubygems.org/gems/mini_magick) in a project a few years ago. It's a pure Ruby gem and invokes ImageMagick's tools via the command-line rather than using the shared libraries like RMagick does, so you may find it easier to install.