# rake error: "warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE"

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-2.0

I've seen similar questions regarding this error, but all of them rails-related. I'm not using rails; I'm working on a local rake task that reads from a yaml file and then does stuff with the data. I'd rather not install bundler for this (the solutions for the similar rails issues suggest prepending with `bundle exec`), since this script is simple and thus shouldn't need it.

Here's the simplified code, (which gets the same error as the code I'm working on):

```
require 'FileUtils'
require 'yaml'

SOME_FILE = "#{Dir.pwd}/some_file.yaml"

task default: :foo

task :foo do
  bar = File.open(SOME_FILE) { |yf| YAML::load( yf ) }
  bar.each {|k,v| puts k}
end
```

And here's the list of errors:

```
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:93: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:93: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:1272: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1272: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:1535: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1535: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:1537: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1537: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:1656: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1656: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/FileUtils.rb:1662: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1662: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
```

The script will run fine despite the warnings; the above code would `puts` the keys as expected, right after the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that these warnings don't appear and the script runs perfectly if I simply comment out or remove line 1 of my original code (`require 'FileUtils'`). Although I haven't browsed the code for Rake, it must already include `FileUtils` (which makes sense).

For the sake of completeness, here is my revised code (note that I removed the `require 'FileUtils'` line:

```
require 'yaml'

SOME_FILE = "#{Dir.pwd}/some_file.yaml"

task default: :foo

task :foo do
  bar = File.open(SOME_FILE) { |yf| YAML::load( yf ) }
  bar.each {|k,v| puts k}
end
```

Comment: in my case zip already includes FileUtils, I thought it that in ruby was used something similar to C, to avoid multiple inclusion?

Answer (score 5):

This warning shows up when I write `require 'FileUtils'`. If I write `require 'fileutils'` (all lower case) warning disappears.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8407062/3670437) link may be helpful explaining the behavior. I think in essence ruby thinks `FileUtils` and `fileutils` are different modules, therefore imports it twice. Then the redeclaration of constants give warning messages.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to answer this clearly (two years after it was asked) in case anyone wanders in here.

First, note that `require` in Ruby does not load a Module, as in the object `FileUtils` that is in memory. It loads the file "fileutils.rb" from your hard drive. The ".rb" is omitted by convention but you could write `require 'fileutils.rb'`.

The purpose of `require` in Ruby is to load a file only once, as opposed to `load` which will reload the file every time it is used. The way `require` avoids loading a file multiple times is by recording the filename argument and skipping it if it if that filename is passed again.

When you first require a file, Ruby responds with true to indicate that it was loaded. If you require the same file again it will return false to indicate that it was already loaded:

```
> require 'fileutils'
=> true
> require 'fileutils'
=> false
```

Since the filename stored by `require` is case-sensitive, but the actual file lookup is not, `fileutils.rb` will still be found if you use caps in the name:

```
> require 'FileUtils'
=> true
```

But if something in your Ruby program already loaded that file *without* caps (in your case "yaml.rb" probably requires "fileutils" as well) you will reload the file and may see warnings:

```
> require 'fileutils'
=> true
> require 'FileUtils'
/bin/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/FileUtils.rb:96: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
etc.
```

By convention Ruby files should be named in lowercase with underscores, e.g. "my_class.rb", so you would always use `require 'my_class'`.

Things get a little trickier if you are requiring using absolute or relative paths, e.g. `require 'special_classes/my_class'`. I suggest reading about `require_relative` and the Ruby load path (`$LOAD_PATH`).

Comment: And a year later, this sure comes in handy. I searched my project dir for "fileutils" and sure enough one of my files required `FileUtils` while the others required `fileutils`. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this similar issue when I list my gem items which named "fileutils" has two versions

```
fileutils (1.1.0, default: 1.0.2)
```

then I run

```
sudo gem uninstall fileutils -v 1.1.0
```

and solved

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Travis and the problem was that I forgot to use `bundle exec rake db:setup` instead of `rake db:setup`. Hope it helps someone :)